# Can json Datasource hold/contain an Image?

Tags: json, image

Hai guys,

I have list of **images**(not image paths) retrieved from sql server database... I am converting that datatable to json... My question

- Can json Datasource hold/contain an Image?

If so how to do it... Any suggestion..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [json.org](http://www.json.org/xml.html):

> JSON does not have a <[CDATA[]]>
>   feature, so it is not well suited to
>   act as a carrier of sounds or images
>   or other large binary payloads.

You could try base64 encoding the data. Some other alternatives are described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64).

Comment: @mopoke ok i ll give a try for base64 encoding

Comment: Your database will be huge. Unecessary waste of resources.

Comment: @dario My database will have only ten images and not more than that..I think it wont be a problem...