# Simple C Program does not give Expected Output

Tags: c

I was writing a small program which was supposed to display a ☻ character to the screen. The program is listed below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("☻\n");
}
```

However, when I run this program, I get the output of

```
Γÿ║
```

Why am I getting this output, and what should I do to get the output I want?

Comment: It works in my terminal (defaults to utf-8).

Comment: You generate code of more than 127. not under 127.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting that because whatever terminal program you're using isn't that compatible with some Unicode encodings.

For example, my Debian box compiles that fine and it actually prints out the smiley face, because `gnome-terminal` is a damn fine piece of software :-)

The fact that you're seeing three characters instead of one is a fairly good indication that it's outputting UTF-8. In fact, if I run that program on my Debian box and capture the binary output with `od -xcb`, I see:

```
0000000    98e2    0abb
        342 230 273  \n
        342 230 273 012
0000004
```

showing that it *is* coming out in UTF-8, it's just that `gnome-terminal` is smart enough to  turn that back into the correct glyph.

Those bytes translate to binary as follows:

```
e2          98          bb
1110 0010 : 1001 1000 : 1011 1011
```

And, using this excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907297/can-utf-8-contain-zero-byte/6907327#6907327), stating that bit patterns starting with `10` are continuation bytes, we can decode it as follows:

```
U+000800-U+00ffff  1110yyyy  yyyyyyyy xxxxxxxx
                   10yyyyxx
                   10xxxxxx

e2          98          bb
1110 0010 : 1001 1000 : 1011 1011
     yyyy     yy yyxx     xx xxxx
```

Hence the code point is `0010 0110 : 0011 1011` which equates to `263b` which, in a total lack of coincidence, is the [black smiling face character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263b/index.htm).

---

In terms of fixing the problem of Windows not displaying Unicode correctly, as indicated by your comment:

> I am on Windows Command Prompt. How should I make cmd.exe work with unicode?

You may want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters), particularly the answer about using `chcp` to change the code page to 65001 (UTF-8). Note I haven't tested this, I provide it only as a pointer for you.

Comment: I am on Windows Command Prompt. How should I make cmd.exe work with unicode?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fcntl.h>

_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
wprintf(L"☻\n");
```

valter