# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 ...: invalid continuation byte in timezone

Tags: python, django

I am doing in UserProfile model this:

```
def repeated_times(self, test, date):
    return self.user.user_test_results.filter(taken_date__month=date.month, djangotest=test).count()
```

but I am getting

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 169: invalid continuation byte
```

because this:  [image]

(bigger image: http://content.screencast.com/users/doniyor/folders/Jing/media/5baf8537-b48f-4194-8b71-384ec880a7b4/2015-10-23_0753.png )

what am I missing?

Comment: I dont want to disable USE_TZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to disable `USE_TZ`, then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Mitteleuropa is the German term for Central Europe. Mitteleuropäische Zeit is Central European Time.

In any case, `0xe4` is indeed a UTF-8 continuation byte and it's in the wrong place for a UTF-8 string since the preceding `p` (`0x70`, `0b01110000`) is [not a character that can be continued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907297/can-utf-8-contain-zero-byte/6907327#6907327) since it doesn't start with a one-bit:

```
Mitteleurop\xe4ische Zeit
```

So I'm thinking that the text you have is actually *not* encoded as UTF-8. In fact, code point `0xe4` is shown as the `ä` character in the original IBM PC code page 437.

Now I'm not sure this is actually a database problem (at least with the specific table you're querying). The actual problem appears to be in your `input` variable which is storing the query:

```
SELECT    something
    FROM  somewhere
    WHERE some condition
    AND   EXTRACT('month' FROM "djtest_result"."taken_date"
            AT TIME ZONE 'Mitteleurop\xe4isch Zeit') = 10
    ...
```

So I'd be looking first at whatever piece of code generated that `input` variable to see if it's the culprit. The timezone may come from the database, or from a config item, or it may be hard-coded. What it *isn't* is valid UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: so `djtest_result.taken_date` is not in utf-8?

Comment: @doniyor, that'd be my (relatively educated) guess.

Comment: but how can a datetimefield not be in utf8, the db itself is in utf8: http://content.screencast.com/users/doniyor/folders/Jing/media/53fe7588-6805-4e2f-ae50-1b77484b25be/2015-10-23_0814.png   any ideas?

Comment: @doniyor, sorry, misunderstood. It's not the DB content that's badly encoded, it's the `extract ... at time zone` clause. No idea where that timezone is coming from. I'll update answer to clarify.

Comment: @Jasper, there's an awful lot of text on the net where it seems to be shown *with* the umlaut (and just as much without), but I'll defer to you for now. I've sent a quick email off to some friends in Munich for confirmation :-)