# Token authentication failed: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, azure-eventhub, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to send the json data from azure ml to eventhub

```
import json
d = result.to_dict(orient='records')
data = json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii=False)
```

this is the screenshot of output of the variable data-[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBU0Q.png)

```
import asyncio
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
from azure.eventhub import EventData
import time
conn_sting = "Endpoint=***"
async def run():
producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn_string)
async with producer:
    # Create a batch.
    event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch(partition_id='0')
    event_data_batch.add(EventData(data))

    # Send the batch of events to the event hub.
    await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
    
nest_asyncio.apply()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
print("sent to eventhub")
```

and getting following error..

```
Token authentication failed: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in 
position 0: invalid continuation byte
Token authentication failed: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in 
position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

anyone could help debug the error?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by the contents of your data dictionary, at least one of the keys or values is not `UTF-8` encoded.

You can try with other encoding types like `"ISO-8859-1"` or `"unicode_escape"`.

You can refer these SO threads for better understanding.

['utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 ...: invalid continuation byte in timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295733/utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe4-invalid-continuation-byte-in-timezone)

["for line in..." results in UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/for-line-in-results-in-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte)