# Is there a differencee between str::as_bytes and CString::as_bytes_with_nul?

Tags: string, rust

Is there any difference between doing this:

```
name.as_bytes()
```

and this:

```
CString::new(name)?.as_bytes_with_nul()
```

I want to get the bytes from `name` (which is `String`) in a way that I can easily send them over the network, and I am not sure whether `CString` is even necessary here.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation of [`as_bytes_with_nul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_bytes_with_nul) starts with:

> Equivalent to the [`as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_bytes) function except that the returned slice includes the trailing nul terminator.

While [`as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_bytes) is:

> The returned slice does **not** contain the trailing nul terminator

(emphasis in the original quote)

It is up to you whether you need to transfer the nul byte, and this depends on how you send data over the network (TCP/UDP? raw binary data over TCP? if so, how do you intend to separate messages? JSON? etc.).

Comment: I should have looked more closely at the docs ... thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is no `0` UTF-8 code unit in your string, `name.as_bytes()` and `CString::new(name)?.as_bytes()` should give you exactly the same bytes. Additionally, `CString`'s `.as_bytes_with_null()` will simply append a `0` byte. Here is a little demo with a reasonably complicated UTF-8 string:

```
use std::ffi::CString;

fn main() {
    let message: String = "\nßщ\u{1F601}".to_string();
    println!("bytes_1: {:?}", message.as_bytes());
    println!("bytes_2: {:?}", CString::new(message.clone()).unwrap().as_bytes());
    println!("bytes_3: {:?}", CString::new(message.clone()).unwrap().as_bytes_with_nul());
}
```

The result is as expected (you might recognize the `10`, which corresponds to the ASCII-character `\n`, which is encoded in the same way in UTF-8):

```
bytes_1: [10, 195, 159, 209, 137, 240, 159, 152, 129]
bytes_2: [10, 195, 159, 209, 137, 240, 159, 152, 129]
bytes_3: [10, 195, 159, 209, 137, 240, 159, 152, 129, 0]
```

The problem arises if your string contains the [`U+0000`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm), [which is a valid Unicode code point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6907327/2707792), is encoded by a single `0` byte in `UTF-8`, and can occur in ordinary Strings. For example:

```
use std::ffi::CString;

fn main() {
    let message: String = "\n\u{0000}\n\u{0000}".to_string();
    println!("bytes_1: {:?}", message.as_bytes());
    println!(
        "bytes_2: {:?}",
        match CString::new(message.clone()) {
            Err(e) => format!("an error: {:?}, as expected", e),
            Ok(_) => panic!("won't happen. .as_bytes() must fail."),
        }
    );
}
```

will give you

```
bytes_1: [10, 0, 10, 0]
bytes_2: "an error: NulError(1, [10, 0, 10, 0]), as expected"
```

So, the simple `.as_bytes()` succeeds, but the `CString`-version fails. I'd suggest to stick to `name.as_bytes()` and UTF-8 if possible, there is no reason to convert it into a CString first.