# Can I store UTF8 in C-style char array

Tags: c, utf-8, c-strings

Follow up
[Can UTF-8 contain zero byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907297/can-utf-8-contain-zero-byte)

Can I safely store UTF8 string in zero terminated `char *` ?

I understand `strlen()` will not return correct information, put "storing", printing and "transferring" the char array, seems to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Just like with ASCII and similiar 8-bit encodings before Unicode, you can't store the `NUL` character in such a string (the value `\u+0000` is the Unicode code point `NUL`, very much like in ASCII).

As long as you know your strings don't need to contain that (and regular text doesn't), it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

In C a 0 byte is the string terminator. As long as the Unicode point 0, U+0000 is not in the Unicode string there is no problem.

To be able to store 0 bytes in Unicode, one may use *modified UTF-8* that convert not only code points >= 128, but also 0 to a multi-byte sequence (every byte thereof having its high bit set, >= 128). This is done in java for some APIs, like DataOutputStream.writeUTF. It ensures you can transmit strings with an embedded 0.

It formally is no longer UTF-8 as UTF-8 requires the *shortest* encoding. Also this is only possible when determining the length i.o. strlen when unpacking to non-UTF-8.

So the most feasible solution is not to accept U+0000 in strings.

Comment: however, if U+0000 is in the string, then input string is not OK anyway.

Comment: Yes nobody uses U+0000 or U+007F (backspace) or U+0008 for any practical purpose as _text_.