# asp mvc REST send image using json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, image, rest

im using the ASP MVC REST implementation and extracting image data from a table and sending it through json what is the best practice in doing this inside the controller?

thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to convert the binary image file as a base64 string on the server before sending it to the client then convert it back into binary on the client.

There's a [great question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64) that describes some of the nuances of this approach

Comment: How about going in the other direction? Uploading an image to an MVC endpoint via JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your image file to Base64 and use it.