# Could I use JSON-RPC to POST a file to a webservice?

Tags: web-services, zend-framework, post, binary-data, json-rpc

I'm looking for viable webservice solution and I just found JSON-RPC which is seducing and seems lightweight (over XML or SOAP for example).

But I'm wondering if I'll be able to post binary DATA using json?

By the way, do you have any feedbacks using `JSON-RPC` and the `ZEnd_Json_ServeR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use base 64 encoding, uuencode or base 85. Look at this answer: [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64/1443240#1443240)

I'm using JSON-RPC with the Zend_Json_Server and it works fine.

Comment: thnak you, yEnc looks interesting