# Base64 incompatible with 7-bit GSM encoding?

Tags: android, sms, base64, 7-bit

Since I am not able to compress a 256-byte long md5-like string within 160 characters, I decided to use Multi-part message in Android to divide the SMS into several parts and the receiver will listen the SMS then combine those messages.

I use the combination algorithm from here: [Android - receiving long SMS (multipart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306020/android-receiving-long-sms-multipart)

And after a few testing I found that the SMS I sent was totally messed, though I encoded them with Base64 before sending.

Thinking the SMS is a 7-bit Encoding method I thought it might be the encoding problem.

But I have successfully sent Base 64 encoded message, but it was short and within 1 SMS.

My question is:

If it is a encoding problem, then why I can send a totally readable Base64 encoded messages within 160 characters, but cannot get a readable result when sending messages exceeding 160 characters?

I've attached my code here:
The string I intend to send:

```
static final String bigNum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
```

The Code

```
private void sendMsg (String phoneNum, String msg) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(msg);
    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNum, null, parts, null, null);
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final String bigNum64 = Base64.encodeToString(bigNum.getBytes(), 0);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMsg("5554", bigNum64);
            textView.setText(bigNum64);
        }
    });
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Bundle receiver = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (receiver != null) {
        String msg = receiver.getString("SMS");
        textView.setText("Received" + msg);
    }
}
}
```

The SMS Receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    String body = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
    }
    SmsMessage sms = messages[0];
    try {
        if (messages.length == 1 || sms.isReplace()) {
            body = sms.getDisplayMessageBody();

        }
        else {
            StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
            }
            body = bodyText.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
    Intent start = new Intent(context, SendLongSMSActivity.class);
    start.putExtra("SMS", body);
    start.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(start);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Related Post: [Any way to compress a 256 bytes "MD5-like" string into 160 bytes or less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853701/any-way-to-compress-a-256-bytes-md5-like-string-into-160-bytes-or-less)

Even if I give a rather simple long string, like

```
"0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF"
```

and no matter with or without Base64 encoding, the receiver cannot get the correct results.

**UPDATE #2**

When using real phone for testing, the receiver can receive correct message without base 64, it was due to **the emulator garbled the text**.

**Question now closed.**

Thanks for everyone who helps! And thanx @Dan

**UPDATE:**

The string "0123456789ABCDEF..." without base64, divided into 2 parts:

```
part [0]    "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF012345678" 

part [1]    "9ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF"
```

Here's the divided base64 string of the "0123456789ABCDEF...:

```
part[0] "MDEyMzQ1Njc4OUFCQ0RFRjAxMjM0NTY3ODlBQkNERUYwMTIzNDU2Nzg5QUJDREVGMDEyMzQ1Njc4\nOUFCQ0RFRjAxMjM0NTY3ODlBQkNERUYwMTIzNDU2Nzg5QUJDREVGMDEyMzQ1Njc4OUFCQ0RFRjAx"    

part[1] "\nMjM0NTY3ODlBQkNERUYwMTIzNDU2Nzg5QUJDREVGMDEyMzQ1Njc4OUFCQ0RFRjAxMjM0NTY3ODlB\nQkNERUY=\n"
```

Comment: Is the base64 string garbled after it gets divided?

Comment: @Dan thanx, seemed the base64 string is not garbled after it gets divided...

Comment: Have you tried to see how a 2 part message is chopped at the divide on the receiving end? Compare it to known good data?

Comment: @Dan I have added the divided string to the original post, pls have a look. thx!

Comment: I put the test Base64 in a decoder and it posted an error, I stripped the "\n"'s and it decoded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the sms divide is adding \n characters after every 77 characters and at the end, just strip those from your string and it will decode properly.

Comment: But if I just send the string "01234567890ABCDEF......"(176 chars) without Base64 encoding, the receiver still gets garbled message, why's that?

Comment: Can you post the garbled text for that, I didn't see it in your latest addition.

Comment: I just figured out, the garbled text was only appeared when I use emulator. When turn to using a real phone for testing, there isn't any problems for sending strings without Base64! Thank you!