# JSON binary encoding

Tags: c#, json, binary

I am building JSon object and I need to output binary data. As I understand I should create JSon string property and put encoded binary data in it? What binary encoding should be used?

Comment: This SO article has some useful discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64

Answer (score 5):

If you want to store binary data inside the JSON object have a look at this question [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)

If you want to transmit your JSON object in binary form you can simply serialize your JSON object into binary stream. Read MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx) on (de)serialization

If you are looking for binary JSON format check http://bsonspec.org/

Answer (score 1):

Further to what aku mentioned, [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) has support for Bson, have a look in the Newtonsoft.Json.Bson Namespace section of their [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) to find out more about the BsonReader and BsonWriter classes. They might give you what you need.

Comment: I will provide public service and if I will use 3rd party method to encode binaries then not all service users may have possibility to decode data.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [native binary json](http://bjson.org). The format is very simple and well defined, however there is lack of open-source implementation at the moment...