# Android Sending Data to PHP Server

Tags: android, json, httprequest

I am creating a sign up form where i need to send the following data to the PHP server to create the user account

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Email
4. PAssword
5. Image

i am sending the first four via JSON. now i am wondering how to include the image and send it to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can transfer byteStream of image by HttpConnection .

i followed this [link](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html) for the same .

Answer (score 2):

for this use the multipartentity concept.
   for reference see the below code

```
MultipartEntity req=new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "icon.png");
        req.addPart("image", bab);
httppost.setEntity(req);
```

in that req.addPart("image", bab);  "image" is the xml code.u sholud collect it .

Answer (score 1):

you should go for **Base64** encoding to send Image to sever.

see this link..[Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to decide what kind of image you want to send. Do you want to choose an image from sd-card or take a photo with camera?

[Here](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/) is very good tutorial how to do it, which even includes explanation how to implement croping of the image.

Next step, you will need to upload this file. You can get good information about that from [here](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html).

Comment: thanks Morphium i have included the cropping already :) will look at the sending part