# PHP: Minify crypted value

Tags: php, encryption, crypt

Is it possible, **to transform a crypted string** (similar to md5), without loosing the ability of decoding it back again?

```
0TJyj0wX4ZCrsYlANG8QgwBHnGzGU7kr1BEkolr6tY0OdowpA==

Better: 73a4842f36b4n237m64as23
```

Comment: By nature, a hash is one direction.  You're looking for a transformation (or potentially encryption.)

Comment: If you want to decode it we are probably talking about encryption. How secure do you want it to be?

Comment: You could just encode/decode and compare the first (or last) bytes returned by `crypt`, but you would get less secure with each byte you remove...otherwise you can only go with Justin's answer I think.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the problem you are trying to solve might be approached in a different way than trying to compress encrypted data. I'd suggest posting a new question with some more detail about what you're trying to achieve. If you do so, link to it here in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash is, by definition, one-way. You would not be able to hash your crypted string and then "un-hash" it to obtain the crypted string again.

You can, however, attempt to "minify" the crypted string by:

- Using a lossless compression algorithm -- though you're unlikely to gain much with this approach since encrypted data doesn't compress well, and for certain input sets compression [can actually *increase* the storage requirements](https://serverfault.com/a/17859/83495).
- Compress the data before encrypting it. Depending on the size of input, it's possible to reduce the size by a few percent over encryption alone (depending on the algorithms), but typically not by more than 5-10% (again, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/17859/83495) points this out)
- Re-encoding the data with a higher "base" (i.e. your string is Base64, you could switch to [Base85](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85)) -- but this only results in a [7% savings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/)

Comment: Lossless compression won't work too well on hashed or encrypted data either, the data will look like random data to the compression algorithm. It's worse than trying to zip a JPEG or MP3 file.

Comment: @owlstead: +1 True, I should have noted that in the answer... edit time!

Comment: Because msec doesn't tell where he need it -> He could encode it binary

Comment: @mabe: Technically speaking, the data *is* in binary -- the string is just a representation of that binary data. The encoding is what specifies how that binary data is represented: hexadecimal (base16), base64, base85. The phrase "encode in binary" doesn't make a lot of sense, unless I'm misunderstanding your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RSA to encrypt you data
see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php), it talks about to crypt in php

Answer (score 0):

Best way to encrypt in PHP is by using the Mcrypt extension.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Example for [encryption](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) and [decryption](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php).

I do recommend also to base64 encode the result of encryption.

Minification does not make sense for small data (ex. passwords).

Comment: I don't think the generic encryption/decryption samples are useful. I would +1 if you would have just posted the last sentence.