# How to send a PDF file via JSON from my REST Service to my clients

Tags: json, rest

Is it possible to send binary data in JSON ? I am creating a REST Service in ASP.NET MVC where i want to return PDF file stored in my server to my clients. How will i do this ? my data transfer medium is JSON & XML.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64) post might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: [how to send pdf in json](http://www.thinkingcode.info/2015/05/how-to-send-pdf-in-json/), it lists couple of approaches that you can consider.

The easiest way is to convert the binary data into string by using Base64 encoding. In C#, this would mean a call to `Convert.FromBase64String`.  However this has space overhead as Base64 encoding means around +33% more memory.

If you can get away with it, this is the least complicated solution. in case additional size is an issue you can think about zipping it up.

Comment: An answer containing only a link is not considered an answer here in SO.

Comment: A compression that *increases* the required space is not really compression. Let's call it an encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a JSON or XML wrapper to your file you'll have to text-encode it, Base 64 for example.