# SBJSON failed with json including binary data

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, sbjson

I'm working with a web service and using sbjson to parse received data like this:

```
NSDictionary *response = [[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]JSONValue];
```

It works well but failed with a json including binary data (application/pdf)
and I got this in the console:

```
-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=6 \"Invalid high character in surrogate pair\" UserInfo=0x1e0e1700 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid high character in surrogate pair}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=6 \"Broken unicode character\" UserInfo=0x1e0e1740 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1e0e1720 \"Invalid high character in surrogate pair\", NSLocalizedDescription=Broken unicode character}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Expected value while parsing array\" UserInfo=0x1e0e1780 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1e0e1760 \"Broken unicode character\", NSLocalizedDescription=Expected value while parsing array}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: content\" UserInfo=0x1e0e17c0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1e0e17a0 \"Expected value while parsing array\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: content}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: params\" UserInfo=0x1e0e1800 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1e0e17e0 \"Object value expected for key: content\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: params}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: request\" UserInfo=0x1e0e18d0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1e0e1890 \"Object value expected for key: params\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: request}"
)

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3397d2a3 0x3314f97f 0x338ce55f 0x339050d3 0x576c1 0x5c631 0x5d9bf 0x389a7ef5 0x388e79f1 0x388e790d 0x36bf65df 0x36bf5ccb 0x36c1e133 0x338c374d 0x36c1e593 0x36b8215d 0x33952683 0x33951ee9 0x33950cb7 0x338c3ebd 0x338c3d49 0x3462c2eb 0x36509301 0x46ab9 0x38548b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Now I wonder how to solve it without move to another json library.
Are there other people else who have ever coped with json including binary?
Thanks!

Comment: NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   Test your json string http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Your problem isn't the JSON library on the client side. It's the invalid JSON data produced by the web service.

Comment: that troublesome json is from google api... ok. nothing more to say. thank you all. I will report this to google

Comment: The Google API has been known to produce invalid JSON from time to time, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [json.org](http://www.json.org) "JSON is a text format". Base64 encode the binary data.

See [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158) "Binary Data in JSON String"