# Read Byte Array From URL and Convert To PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, arrays

I have a service in Windows that returns a PDF data, which it's in the database in a varbinary field. This service returns the PDF data as a Byte Array in JSON format 
How can I read this data and convert it to PDF again, in my app in Xcode?
Which is the correct structure data to retrieve this byte array? NSArray? NSMutableArray?
I want to store this data, and I'm using a NSData structure...
Thanks

Comment: You don't do this in Xcode. You do it in your iOS app.

Comment: Ok. In my App using Xcode

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I thougt my point was clear. It'a obvious I'm developing in objective-c using Xcode as ide. But the next time i'll be more specific

Answer (score 0):

An `NSArray` would be for arrays of objects, you want an array of bytes, which an `NSData` is.

To get the data out of JSON, you would use the `NSJSONSerialization` class to extract the data from your JSON object -- the deserializer will probably return your literal data as an `NSString`, which you then would convert into an `NSData` by decoding it.

Presumably your raw data [is in the JSON as Base64 or some such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64).