# How to convert binary string to bytes[] array?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

Since Mozilla's `btoa` and `atob` aren't compatible with IE, Im using [Nick Galbreath's solution](https://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/javascript/base64.js) that works across the board.

In my JS, I have this snippet:

```
reader.onload = function (e)
{
    var base64str = e.target.result.split(';')[1].split(',')[1];
    var binaryData = base64.decode(base64str); 
    
    // binaryData looks like: 3!1AQa"q2¡±B#$RÁb34rÑC%Sðáñcs5¢²&DTdEÂ£t
    // 6ÒUâeò³ÃÓuãóF'¤´ÄÔäô¥µÅÕåõVfv¦¶ÆÖæö7GWgw§·Ç×ç÷5!1AQaq"2¡±B#ÁRÑð
    // 3$bárCScs4ñ%¢²&5ÂÒDT£dEU6teâò³ÃÓuãóF¤´ÄÔäô¥µÅÕåõVfv¦¶ÆÖæö'7GWgw
    // §·ÇÿÚ?õTI%)$IJI$RIrÿ[múÙxÝ^«ÝKØrþk²ïÑûíGóß÷¿ÑþÄY«ÍÓ±×úN //...
    // Is this even binary data?

    Ajax.SendToHandler(binaryData);
}
```

How do I convert `binaryData`, which is sent to my ashx derived `IHttpHandler` as a string, into a `bytes[]` array?

Ask me to clarify where needed!

Comment: What is `binary string` ? What is the reason for tagging it c#?

Comment: I say binary string, because the `atob` function, or `base64.decode` should convert ascii to binary (a to b). `binaryData` holds the result of the decoding, which is in my snippet above, which I called the 'binary string'. It is very likely I'm using the wrong terminology.

Comment: I tagged c# because it goes to my ashx handler, where I need to convert the `binaryData` from `HttpContext['binaryData']` into a `byte[]` array.

Comment: show us your binarydata

Comment: It's large to post here, but a very small portion is in the snippet above. Do you need more?

Comment: Why not sending the base64 string as it is and decode it on the server? Base64 is exactly for sending binary data as text.

Comment: Besides that it adds 33% inflation to the filesize, I'm required not to do so. There can be up to 25 images getting uploaded at one time, so we'd like to minimize the wait time as much as possible. Your thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64 - there are a lot of ideas about compressing base64 data. Maybe it  helps?

Comment: @Josh When uploading files over HTTP, doesn't the binary data get MIME-encoded anyway? (Or something like that. I'm not really sure what all the variables in this setup are.)

Comment: I can't say whether it does or doesn't, since I'm not as familiar as I'm trying to be with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data string seems to contain only extended ASCII characters (probably either Windows-1252 characters or ISO 8859-1 characters). You should try using a `System.Text.Encoding` to convert it to bytes.

Comment: So I actually did that using `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes`. However, to do a sanity check, I convert it to base 64  in the handler and see if the result is the same on the back-end as it is on the front-end before its decoded, and they're not the same. Thoughts?

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII` is no good due to being limited to 0-127. Try `Encoding.Default` or `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")`.

Comment: You, my friend, are a god-send. May I ask how you knew what type of encoding to use?

Comment: The letters are mostly accented letters, but nothing that looks overtly non-Latin (such as japanese, cyrillic, etc.)

Comment: Let me ask you this, is the encoding browser dependent? Will the encoding be different for users on different browsers on different machines?

Comment: This is outside my competences, sorry.

Comment: Do you know how to escape/unescape the binary string in the handler to avoid `System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException`?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Usually I just use base64 wherever possible.