# Stream reader.Read number of character

Tags: c#, stream, arrays, reader

Is there any Stream reader Class to read only number of `char` from `string` Or `byte` from `byte[]`?

forexample reading string:

```
string chunk = streamReader.ReadChars(5); // Read next 5 chars
```

or reading bytes

```
byte[] bytes = streamReader.ReadBytes(5); // Read next 5 bytes
```

Note that the return type of this method or name of the class does not matter. I just want to know if there is some thing similar to this then i can use it.

I have `byte[]` from midi File. I want to Read this midi file in C#. But i need ability to read number of bytes. or chars(if i convert it to hex). To validate midi and read data from it more easily.

Comment: You can use [StreamReader.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824(v=vs.110).aspx) - "Reads a specified maximum of characters from the current stream into a buffer, beginning at the specified index."

Comment: You probably looking for `BinaryReader`. Classes deriving from `TextReader` are generally text-oriented... Note that all of them require `Stream` as source - which is what `MemoryStream` for.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you. Your comment was actually an answer. what i need is MemoryStream.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - ok - consider to find good duplicate... or convert my answer to comment if you want. I though [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598021/how-to-read-byte-with-current-encoding-using-streamreader) that asks  about particular encoding would be ok duplicate, but it already shows answer in the question - so not really fair.

Comment: yes. i got it. how ever i dont need stream reader. because i need bytes even for Hex i need bytes too and memorystream read bytes. @AlexeiLevenkov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I didnt know there is an Overload for Read Methods. i could achieve this with FileStream.

```
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            byte[] chunk = new byte[4];
            fileStream.Read(chunk, 0, 4);
            string hexLetters = BitConverter.ToString(chunk); // 4 Hex Letters that i need!
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! filestream did straight job! @AlexeiLevenkov

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing something like below but I am not sure this will applicable for your problem or not.

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
 StringBuilder S = new StringBuilder();
 while(true)
 {
 S = S.Append(sr.ReadLine());
 if (sr.EndOfStream  == true)
      {
         break;
      }
 }
```

Once you have value on "S", you can consider sub strings from it.