# Can json transfer longblob in php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I used mysql to store the picture and it is stored by `longblob`.
Now I need use `json` the transfer the data of `longblob`.
The `json_endcode($data)` returns `null`.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to serialize image data to base64, but it seems to be a bad idea, since images can be really big. You better store it on ftp server and write just links to images to database

Comment: I need to store the message of String ,pictures and voice, so I used the  longblob to store all kinds of data in mysql. Do you have some better idea in this situation.

Comment: Just imagine your database size after couple month of highload. rdbms aint a silver bullet, you don't want to store everything there

Answer (score 1):

Please check this question - [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)

binary data can be encoded into base64    otherwise JSON does not support it

> The JSON format natively doesn't support binary data. The binary data
>   has to be escaped so that it can be placed into a string element (i.e.
>   zero or more Unicode chars in double quotes using backslash escapes)
>   in JSON.