# Get image blob data to an android application with json

Tags: php, android, json, blob

I have to show some data in my android application from a external database including an image. I have successfully got text data from the database. Here is my php code. Now I need to get blob data. How can I achieve this..?

```
$id=$_POST['ID'];

$db_server = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database,$db_server);

    $result=mysql_query("select * from names where ID=$id");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $output[]=$row;
    }

    print(json_encode($output));

    mysql_close($db_server);
```

?>

Answer (score -3):

Its not recommend to pass blob data in json, use url of that image for passing in response.

Comment: Images are inside the database. I think there is no unique url for each image.

Comment: That's what i am saying don't keep image in database for better performance. But if you want to do same way you have to send as bytes.

Comment: Do u have an idea how can I send the image as bytes?

Comment: Refer 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64