# How to retrieve an image from mysql using json?

Tags: java, mysql, json, arrays, blob

I'm trying to get a blob from my mysql but using json. Here is my code:

```
public class ClubVO {
    private long _id;
    private String nom = null;
    private byte[] imageClub = null;
    public long getId() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void setId( long aId ) {
        this._id = aId;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom( String aNom ) {
        this.nom = aNom;
    }
    public byte[] getImage() {
        return imageClub;
    }
    public void setImage( byte[] aImage ) {
        this.imageClub = aImage;
    }
}
```

Here is the function I use to retrieve my json object:

```
public List<ClubVO> consultPlacesByName() throws Exception {
    String[] resposta = new WebServiceClient().get( URL_WS );

    if ( resposta[0].equals("200") ) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<ClubVO> lListaPlaces = new ArrayList<ClubVO>();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray lJasonArray = parser.parse(resposta[1]).getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < lJasonArray.size(); i++)
            lListaPlaces.add( gson.fromJson( lJasonArray.get(i), ClubVO.class ) );
        return lListaPlaces;
    } else {
        throw new Exception( resposta[1] );
    }
}
```

Here is what I am getting with this code:

```
{"_id":15,"nom":"Musée d'art Contemporain de Montréal","imageClub":"[B@25450aa2"}
```

Just one more thing, my column is blob type.

Comment: You don't explain exactly why what you are getting with this code is wrong. Do you mean that 8 bytes is not the expected length?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)

Comment: You need to serialize the image to byte[], then encode the bytes into string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that instead of the real image bytes you have the hashcode of the byte array in the json data: "[B@25450aa2"
To solve the problem when you serialize the object you need to use

```
new String(Base64.encodeBase64(byteArray))
```

and when you parse the json data you need to do the opposite:

```
Base64.decodeBase64(jsonString.getBytes())
```