# cakephp serialize image to json object

Tags: json, image, cakephp

I am storing image as longBLOB in database.my table structure is as follow

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `body` text,
 `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `image` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
).
```

I need to send this image with all other data in json format. my code in controller is

```
public function index() 
{
        $this->set(array('posts'=> $this->Post->find('all'),
                 '_serialize' => array('posts')));
}
```

when I goto localhost/app/posts.json I get all data in json format but for image I am getting null.

```
{"Post":{"id":"1","title":"The title","body":"This is the post body.","created":"2013-    11-11 16:32:45","modified":null,"user_id":"1","image":null}
```

I have found some solutions stating that store image path in database and convert it to JSON and send it to server but I don't want to store image path in databse,So Can anyone help me send image in JSON format?

Answer (score 1):

I would not store images in the database, but well, your choice.

Use base64 to encode the binary date, see [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64) for example.