# Messaging - send an identification key or the complete dataset

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message

I have a simple question about messaging.  I have two applications that communicate via RabbitMQ.  The first application regularly sends messages to say "New data has arrived".  The second application subscribes to these messages and looks up the information in a common database if it is interested.  So the questions is:  Should the messages be structured as an alert and an ID so that the second application can do a look up to retrieve the data or should the message contain the complete data set so that a look up is not required?  The message content is around 1KBytes.  I guess to some extent this is a stylistic question, but I am curious to know if there is an accepted "Best Practice"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending binary file through RabbitMQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070639/sending-binary-file-through-rabbitmq)

Comment: thank you for the referral, however my requirement is straight ASCII

Comment: Size of message is the issue here not format. Its all bytes.

Comment: ok - that's a good point.  I guess I was thinking more of the 'process' - leave the data in one place and do look ups to get at it or send the data in the message.  If there were many listeners it would make sense to send the data to minimize look ups..... where as if there was just one listener maybe it doesn't matter?

Comment: did you find any "Best Practice" , if found plz tell me, me too trying to find one.

Comment: @ faisalbhagat we ended up using a hybrid.  We send a basic set of data in the message - enough for some types of transactions.  For a process that requires additional information it does a look up via web services.  Hope this helps.