# Send files through RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Is it a good idea to send files with size about 1Mb through RabbitMQ? I want to send message in json format with binary fields corresponding to the files.

And how to do it properly using spring-amqp? Just by publishing object with next class?

```
class Message {
    String field1;
    byte[] fileField1;
    byte[] fileField2;
}
```

Comment: Read here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-discuss/ZYsqJt422cQ

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending binary file through RabbitMQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070639/sending-binary-file-through-rabbitmq), also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842096/can-rabbitmq-be-used-for-avatars-in-a-chat-server

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest not only reading those links that were posted but also, doing some of your own experimentation. The thing I would be concerned about is performance at the service level and at the client level.

You might want to consider having a server host the files/data and allow rabbitmq just send the message to the consumer with the id of the message in it. So when your consumer gets the message, it sends an HTTP GET request to a service that requests the actual message payload. That way RabbitMQ stays lightweight. You can always add consumers and servers if you need.

That's my opinion without experimenting. You might find that it's still lighting fast with 1MB payloads. That's why I would say to experiment and find out for yourself.

Hope you find this helpful!