# python: how to store an image or file as StringIO and store it as postgresql bytea later?

Tags: python, postgresql, rabbitmq, celery

basically I want to download an image, convert it to stringio, and then insert it into a bytea column in my postgresql later.

Is stringio the right way to do this, or should you just use a tempfile module instead?

the script that downloads the image cannot connect to postgresql directly, it needs to pass the image data to a rabbitmq queue, and a celery worker that will then connect to the database and insert the images in the queue to the postgresql database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can rabbitMQ be used for avatars in a chat server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842096/can-rabbitmq-be-used-for-avatars-in-a-chat-server)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175543/send-files-through-rabbitmq

Comment: this has nothing to do with avatars, and is not a duplicate.