# Select blob/image from database returns NULL

Tags: php, json, blob

Here is a code how I push image into database:

```
$title = $_REQUEST['title'];
$description = $_REQUEST['description'];
$image = $_REQUEST['image'];
$bdata = addslashes($image);

$query = "insert into Images (title, description, image) values ($title, $description, '$bdata')" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($connection));

$result = $connection->query($query);
$connection->close();
```

I double checked in database and it stores successfully.

Here is a code which gets data from the table:

```
$query = "select * from Images" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($connection));
$result = $connection->query($query);
$events = array();

while ($event = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {       

    $events[] = $event;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($events);

$result->free();
$connection->close();
```

As result I receive next json:

```
{
id: "34",
title: "some image",
description: "some description",
image: null
}
```

As you can see "image" field is null. In phpAdmin I see that there is a data.

Comment: Don't use "SELECT *". Name the columns you actually want returned. (We've got no chance otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

First: Use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to get rid of that annoying [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

---

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) has no native support for binary data:

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array.

Use something like [Base64](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php), [BSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON), [Smile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smile_%28Data_Interchange_Format%29) or [UBJSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBJSON). See also: [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)