# JSON and binary data - encoding

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am relatively new to JSON.  I have recently added JQuery and JavaScript to an application to make it more interactive and quicker.  I understand how JSON works for basic types like: Strings, Numbers etc where there is a MAP i.e. a key and a value.  For example: http://www.w3schools.com/json/.  Here there is an Employees list, where each employee has two keys i.e. first name and last name and two values i.e. first name value and last name value.

However, I do not understand how binary data fits into the equation.  Say I was to add a new property to the Employee object called: Video, which is a type: `application/octet-stream` like in the question: [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64) and the value was:

```
TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCBieSB0aGlz
    IHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2Yg
    dGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2Ugb2YgZGVsaWdodCBpbiB0aGUgY29udGlu
    dWVkIGFuZCBpbmRlZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gb2Yga25vd2xlZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRo
    ZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=
```

How is this data represented as a MAP? I realise this is probably a simple question, however I do have a JSON book but it does not go into that much detail.  I have not found an answer on the web either.

Comment: This data is supposed to go in a string, not in a map. However, I don't think it's a good idea to encode a video in JSON, rather just put a link to it in the JSON and load it separately.

Comment: @Bergi, are you saying that you can put anything you want into a JSON string i.e. it does not have to be in the format of: { "data" : { "field1" : "value1", "field2" : "value2"}}

Comment: @w0051977 what he means it that you put it as a string value of a json property. Like `{"video": "TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCBieSB0aGlzIHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2YgdGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2Ugb2YgZGVsaWdodCBpbiB0aGUgY29udGludWVkIGFuZCBpbmRlZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gb2Yga25vd2xlZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRoZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4="}`

Comment: No, by "string" I did not mean the whole "JSON string" but *a string in the JSON*, such as `"value1"` or `"value2"` in your example

Comment: @souldcheck, of course.  Thanks for that.  Do you have to use key value pairs for JSON? I cannot see the key in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are giving "maps" (KV pairs) too much value. As you've pointed out, JSON has a small number of types: numbers, strings, `true` and `false`, `null`, arrays, and objects. You can think of objects and "maps" as being the same thing. Objects can be built up of the other types, for example:

```
{
    "person": {
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

Person is an object that has a name property that is a string.

So, if you want to represent binary data in JSON, you will have to use one of the existing types (usually as a string via Base64). In the example given in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1443158/), the `value` property of the object is the Base64-encoded value of the file.

```
{
    "mimetype" : "application/octet-stream”,
    "metadata" : [ ],
    "value" :   "TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCBieSB0aGlzIHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2YgdGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2Ugb2YgZGVsaWdodCBpbiB0aGUgY29udGludWVkIGFuZCBpbmRlZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gb2Yga25vd2xlZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRoZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=",
}
```

If you are familiar with JavaScript, the following would give you the Base64-encoded value as a string:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var value = obj.value; // This is a string
```

Comment: Thanks but what is the key in the above example? I understand the value is the binary data.

Comment: The key would be `value` and it's value would be a string, not binary.