# Send and receive a blob in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express, blob

I want to send a blob using a JQuery ajax request and receive it server-side with Node.js + express.

I would send the blob as a JSON string, but it seems that none of the binary data is included in it:

```
{"type":"audio/wav","size":344108}
```

How else could it be sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON doesn't support binary data. You will have to encode your binary data first: [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)