# Writing binary chunk to boost property tree stored as json

Tags: c++, json, serialization, boost, boost-propertytree

Is it possible to write a binary chunk, serialized as *"(uint32 numbytes) (chunk)"* via stream operators, to *json* via a boost property tree?

To be more specific, lets say the binary chunk is a `std::vector` of floats, and my iostream serializer parses the number of bytes as an int, followed the actual data.

Comment: For an discussion of using binary data in JSON, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64

Answer (score 1):

Just encode it into a string (e.g. using base64) and store that.

You can automate this for your custom types by specializing `boost::property_tree::translator_between`.

However, this customization point does /not/ facilitate streaming operation, so it will not be efficient for (very) large vectors.

Consider using a Bson/Json library for the purpose instead.