# Encoding the compressed data into json string

Tags: php, json, gzip

I am compressing the array as below,

```
<?php
    $input = array('name'=>'PHP');
    $compressed = gzcompress(serialize($input));

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($compressed);
?>
```

And it is printing the data as below

```
xœK´2´ª.¶2±RÊKÌMU².¶2¶R
ðP²®nJ»
```

Now, I would like to convert `$compressed` as a json string. Since the compressed data contains special characters, it throws error, So I tried `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` below is the code snippet.

```
<?php
    // $compressed value getting from above script
    echo json_encode($compressed,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Still it is not working. Can anyone suggest how to encode a compressed data as a json string.

Comment: You might want to look into this earlier post on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try by using:

```
$data = base64_encode(gzcompress(serialize($input)));
```

To revert back:

```
$input = unserialize(gzuncompress(base64_decode($data)));
```

Comment: welcome to SO. I found the solution also. Appreciate your interest and enthusiasm to post answer on old questions. :-)

Comment: How can unserialize from client side? Say, Javascript or dart?