# PostgreSQL 9.4 attachments in JSONB

Tags: postgresql, attachment, jsonb

How can I insert attachments to JSONB using PostgreSQL ?

Is any special key, like "_attachments:{}" ? Where Can I find in manual, about inserting files, binary data, attachments ?

Comment: What's an "attachment"? Are you just asking "how do I store binary data in json"?

Comment: Yes. By saying attachment, I mean binary data like jpg images, pdf, word document, text files or other files.

Answer (score 2):

This really has nothing to do with PostgreSQL its self, it's down to the JSON object-serialization format, rather than PostgreSQL's implementation of it.

JSON is a text-based serialization, so you cannot embed binary data in it directly.

You must *encode* it to a form that's valid encoded text with no null bytes, etc.

Typically you do this by encoding it as base64 or base85.

In PostgreSQL you'll want to use `encode(some_bytea, 'base64')` and the corresponding `decode` call. PostgreSQL doesn't have built-in base85 support.

See:

- [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1443158/398670)

Comment: Is this mean, that attachments in PostgreSQL have not any special meaning like in CouchDB ? What is performance if I would like to store 1MB 10MB or 4GB documents for some reason ? I think, I could reach limit for key value length (if there is any), so 4GB document could exceed this limit ? Also, did this mean, that I should keep attachments as separated documents, for increase search, get, update operation ?

Comment: @InnerWorld I don't know CouchDB or what it considers an "attachment" so I can't really say. Performance-wise: test and see. It depends on too many factors for a generic answer to make any sense. You're correct that size is an issue; the maximum size of the datum is 1GB, but you'll probably be able to store quite a bit less than 1GB because of base64 encoding.

Comment: Also, remember that like any composite field, when you update any part of the field the whole field must be copied due to MVCC.

Comment: It sounds like the underlying question here is something like "can I use PostgreSQL with a single table with a single jsonb column like a CouchDB document store". If so, the answer is "not really". Anyway, please post new questions if you want to go into more depth.