# How to send list of byte array as json parameter in Java(Android)?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I need to send a list of byte[] as json parameter to .net(wcf) server. Is it possible? or should I do base64 encoding and proceed?

For example, I need to pass a sessionId(`String`) and datalist(`ArrayList<byte[]>`) in a json object. I am using Retrofit Library, creating request model POJO and sending.  sessionId is recieved in the server, but for 'datalist', server is recieving null.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should needed to convert the byte array to base64.

Comment: I am sending to WCF restful service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)

Comment: You want to send it as payload or as form data

Comment: do you want to send this arraylist as json to the server

Comment: I want to put arraylist as one property of json, sessionId another property to server

Comment: check my edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this is how to send JSON data to restful web service:

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
ArrayList<byte[]>arrayList=new ArrayList<byte[]>();
Iterator<byte[]> itr=arrayList.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
        byte[] bs = (byte[]) itr.next();
        JSONObject temp=new JSONObject();
        temp.put("byte",bs.toString());
        jsonArray.put(temp);
}

// create HttpClient

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonArray.toString());

se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
post.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
// convert inputstream to string
```

Comment: Arpit, this is not what I asked. I want to do something like this   JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("sessionId", "some String");                jsonObject.put("datalist", "some list of byte[] here");                                                                           By Googling, I found I need to encode the bytes in order to send. i need a conformation on that whether that is necessary, because encoding makes the size larger

Comment: Sorry folk, I made a little mistake in typing the code. Check the edit.