# Efficient storage of binary data in JWT's Payload Private Claim Value

Tags: c#, binary, base64, jwt, claims-based-identity

I need to efficiently store a `byte[]` into a *[JWT claim](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token#payload) value specifically*.

Is there anything more efficient than converting the `byte[]` to base64URL?
i.e.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.Base64UrlTextEncoder.Encode(arrToEnc);
```

Ultimate goal is to encode a `List<UInt16>` such that each `UInt16` is at most 2 bytes(*after normal JWT decode*).

Considering `byte[]` -> UTF8 String.  i.e. `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arrToEnc);`

This is completely separate from how JWT's in general use Base64 to encode them...

Thanks..

Comment: Could you compress the content to zip before base64 encoding? Base64 adds 33% overhead. Probably compression is greater

Comment: An alternative is base85, but it only improves 7℅ over base64, is not common and implementations could not support it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64 I suggest compression

Comment: I can and will use gzip. I will write the encoder and decoder so uncommon is ok.  I think ultimately the solution depends on the charset of the 'string' in the claim value.  And I encode to that base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base64 adds 33℅ overhead, but could be lesser, depends on the content. An alternative is base85, but it only improves 7℅ over base64, is not common and implementations could not support it.  It is not a problem if you control the  encoder and decoder. 
See [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)

You could compress the content. The worst case with base64 is 33℅,  The compression ratio you will get will zip is about 30-40℅, but JWT will do an additional base64 encoding when compacting, so even using base85,  you will have an overload on your required ratio of 1: 1

You can also add gzip  to your server, then the compression ratio will be applied over the full JWT content