# curl command a gzipped POST body to an apache server

Tags: apache, curl, post, compression, gzip

With mod_deflate properly activated on my apache 2.2 server, I am trying to send a gzipped body via curl command line.

All tutorials I have seen say to add -H'Content-Encoding: gzip' and gzip my body file, however this fails:

```
echo '{ "mydummy" : "json" }' > body
gzip body
curl -v -i http://localhost/mymodule -H'Content-Encoding: gzip' --data-binary @body.gz
```

My apache module receives 0 bytes

And in my apache error.log if LogLevel is set to debug I get:
`[Thu Jun 01 14:29:03 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(900): [client 127.0.0.1] Failed to inflate input: cannot handle deflate flags`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The thing is that mod_deflate does not like the gzip header shown here:

```
hexdump -C body.gz
00000000  1f 8b 08 08 20 08 30 59  00 03 62 6f 64 79 00 ab  |.... .0Y..body..|
00000010  56 50 ca ad 4c 29 cd cd  ad 54 52 b0 52 50 ca 2a  |VP..L)...TR.RP.*|
00000020  ce cf 53 52 a8 e5 02 00  a6 6a 24 99 17 00 00 00  |..SR.....j$.....|
00000030
```

The solution is simply to give it to gzip without the intermediate file step, if taking a stream, it will not print the headers and apache will like the body!

```
echo '{ "mydummy" : "json" }' | gzip > body.gz
curl -v -i http://localhost/mymodule -H'Content-Encoding: gzip' --data-binary @body.gz
```

This works, the apache module receives the decompressed bytes.

You can see the header difference here, you no longer see the file name (body) in the gzip file:

```
hexdump -C body.gz
00000000  1f 8b 08 00 08 0a 30 59  00 03 ab 56 50 ca ad 4c  |......0Y...VP..L|
00000010  29 cd cd ad 54 52 b0 52  50 ca 2a ce cf 53 52 a8  |)...TR.RP.*..SR.|
00000020  e5 02 00 a6 6a 24 99 17  00 00 00                 |....j$.....|
0000002b
```

Comment: Use `--data-binary` probably instead of `-d` to make it safer.

Comment: Whats the difference between `--data-binary` & `-d`?

Comment: @JayaAnanthram See man page of curl: "When --data is told to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out"

Answer (score 22):

Single line:

```
echo '{"mydummy": "json"}' | gzip | curl -v -i --data-binary @- -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" http://localhost/mymodule
```

Comment: Also add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` otherwise data will be sent as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`