# Decompressing data received as binary data in lambda - incorrect header check

Tags: node.js, curl, post, aws-lambda, gzip

I want to send compressed data (gzip) to some URL that will trigger a (proxy) lambda function, that will decompress the data.

The lambda function (NodeJS 8):

```
let zlib = require('zlib');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let decompressedData = zlib.gunzipSync(event['body'])
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": decompressedData.toString()
    };
};
```

I trigger it with a curl command to the URL (through API gateway), for some file that I compressed `example.gz` with gzip:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @example.gz https://URL...
```

As a result, I get:

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

And the error is (logs in Cloudwatch):

```
   "errorMessage": "incorrect header check",
    "errorType": "Error",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Gunzip.zlibOnError (zlib.js:153:15)",
        "Gunzip._processChunk (zlib.js:411:30)",
        "zlibBufferSync (zlib.js:144:38)",
        "Object.gunzipSync (zlib.js:590:14)",
        "exports.handler (/var/task/test_index.js:5:33)"
    ]
```

When I looked at the `event['body']` itself, I see the exact data as I see in `example.gz`. Perhaps I need some special header? I just want to pass the data as is.

Comment: Please post event body

Comment: By default, API Gateway can't pass binary data into a Lambda function's `event['body']` without corrupting it, since it's binary data and `event['body']` is a string, passed to Lambda in JSON.  It will need to be wrapped in base-64.  Your string may look the same, but it almost certainly is not byte-for-byte identical once it arrives at the Lambda function. 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks! Please add your comment as an answer so I can at least reward you for directing me to the solution. Anyway, I added my answer.

Comment: @sheldonzy thank you for the offer, but your answer is perfectly good.  I pointed you in the right direction but you ran with it, and solved it, so +1 from me. I'll take no offense if you mark your own answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) said, By default, API Gateway can't pass binary data into a Lambda function.

What worked for me:
I added the header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` in the curl command, and in the API gateway settings, on `Binary Media Types` I added `application/octet-stream`.

This way, the data is passed in base64, and afterwards I just converted the date that is in base64 to a buffer:

```
let data = Buffer.from(event['body'], "base64")
```

And afterwards just decompress it.

For more information [read here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html)

Answer (score 0):

1/ First you need to build your gzip correctly, ensure that gzip file header is not present : [curl command a gzipped POST body to an apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307771/curl-command-a-gzipped-post-body-to-an-apache-server)

Wrong way :

```
echo '{ "mydummy" : "json" }' > body
gzip body
hexdump -C body.gz
00000000  1f 8b 08 08 20 08 30 59  00 03 62 6f 64 79 00 ab  |.... .0Y..body..|
00000010  56 50 ca ad 4c 29 cd cd  ad 54 52 b0 52 50 ca 2a  |VP..L)...TR.RP.*|
00000020  ce cf 53 52 a8 e5 02 00  a6 6a 24 99 17 00 00 00  |..SR.....j$.....|
00000030
```

Good way :

```
echo '{ "mydummy" : "json" }' | gzip > body.gz
hexdump -C body.gz
00000000  1f 8b 08 00 08 0a 30 59  00 03 ab 56 50 ca ad 4c  |......0Y...VP..L|
00000010  29 cd cd ad 54 52 b0 52  50 ca 2a ce cf 53 52 a8  |)...TR.RP.*..SR.|
00000020  e5 02 00 a6 6a 24 99 17  00 00 00                 |....j$.....|
0000002b
```

2/ In curl don't forget to specify the content-encoding with

```
-H "Content-Encoding: gzip"
```

3/ In addition if you use express+compress you don't need to call zlib

```
 curl -X POST "http://example.org/api/a" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @body.gz

router.post("/api/a", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body); // { mydummy: 'json' }
});
```

Comment: Actually I'm currently doing it with `Content-Encoding: gzip`, but it is so slow I want to try to decompress in the lambda itself.