# Is there a better way to create a Spring DTO to get a file or a folder containing files than encoding in base64 string?

Tags: java, spring, rest, web, spring-restcontroller

At the moment, the file's content is transferred in a JSON like this :

```
{ 
  "name" : "filename.txt",
  "path" : "src/info/filename.txt",
  "base64content" : "dGhpcyBpcyBhIGZpbGUgd2l0aCBjb250ZW50"
}
```

I just want to know how you would structure the JSON (and possibly the DTO class object) ?

Comment: Do you really need both the path and the data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64

Comment: Yes I do need both @MartinByers

Comment: As for your answer @StanislavL, I understand that it says that base64 is pretty standard for binary data transfer and I guess in my situation, where file transfer won't be too frequent, it's okay.

Comment: Base64 is fine but there is alternative described there - a way to pass binary data as multipart/form-data

Comment: You can write bytes in outputstream. It's fairly fast and consumes a few memory.