# Java decompress HTTP GZIP content from json attribute

Tags: java, json, gzip, httpresponse, packetbeat

We are working with packetbeat, a network packet analyzer tool to capture http requests and http responses. Packebeat persists this packet events in json format. The problem comes when the server supports gzip compression, packetbeat could not unzip content and save it directly the gzip content as json attribute. As you can see (Note: json has been simplified);

```
{
 {
     ... ,
     "content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
     "transfer-encoding":"chunked",
     "content-length":6347,
     "x-application-context":"proxy-service:pre,native:8080",
     "content-encoding":"gzip",
     "connection":"keep-alive",
     "date":"Mon, 18 Dec 2017 07:18:23 GMT"
 },
 "body": "\u001f\ufffd\u0008\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003\ufffd]k\ufffd\u0014Ǳ\ufffd/\ufffdYI\ufffd#\ufffd*\ufffdo\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0002\t\u0010^\ufffd\u001c\u000eE=\ufffd{\ufffdb\ufffd\ufffdE\ufffd\ufffdC\ufffd\ufffdf\ufffd,\ufffd\u003e\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u001ef\u001a\u0008\u0005\ufffd\ufffdg\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdYYU\ufffd\ufffd;\ufffdoN\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdg\ufffd\u0011UdK\ufffd\u0015\u0015\ufffdo\u000eH\ufffd\u000c\u0015Iq\ndC\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd ... "
}
```

We are thinking in preprocess packet json files to unzip content. Could someone tell me what i need to decompress zipped "body" json attribute using java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is irrecoverably broken. Generally I would suggest using Base64 encoding for transferring binary data packed into JSON, but you can read about possible alternatives in [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64) if you like experimenting.

Otherwise, in theory you could just use a variant of [`String.getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) to get an array of bytes, and wrap the result into the mentioned (in the other answer) streams:

```
byte bodyBytes[]=body.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(bodyBytes);
GZipInputStream gis=new GZipInputStream(bais);
<do something with gis here, perhaps use an additional DataInputStream>
```

Apart from the String-thing (which is usually not a good idea), this is how you unpack a gzip-compressed array of bytes.
However valid gzip data starts with a magic number 0x1F,0x8B (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format), or you can also dig up the actual specification). Your data starts with 0x1F (the `\u001F` part), but continues with a `\ufffd` Unicode character, which a replacement character (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) again).
Some tool was encoding the binary data and did not like the 0x8B, most probably because it was >=0x80. If you further read in your JSON, there are many `\ufffd`-s in it, all values above (or equal to) 0x80 have been replaced with this. So the data at the moment is irrecoverably broken even if JSON would support raw binary data inside (but it does not).

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use the GZIPInputStream class to decode the GZIP data, I think you would need to turn the value into a ByteArrayInputStream first.

Comment: We are trying to decompress gzip data using gzipinputstream class but as you said, previously the body attribute content in string format should be converted to byte array format and are not able to convert it. Any idea?