# Error converting Data to JSON in ColdFusion

Tags: json, sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have an application that has MS SQL Server as the backend database, ColdFusion server and front end is Angular. I am getting the following error when trying to retrieve data from a few tables in the database. It doesn't impact all data but only a few tables

> message=JSON serialization failure: Unable to serialize binary data to JSON

Code to serialize data:

```
<cfset responseString = serializeJSON( apiResponse.data )>
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please format any error messages and code different from the rest of your text to make them easier to read for others.

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward. You cannot serialize binary data to JSON. The data will need to be encoded first.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1443158/1636917

Comment: @Miguel-F Your comment helped me approach the issue differently and find a solution

Comment: Glad it helped you. Please post your solution as an answer to your question. It is okay to do that and will help others that have similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue with Miguel's direction. The SQL Server database included a few tables which were migrated from another Access database and these tables included a column named **SSMA_Timestamp**. The value in this column was a binary one. I cleansed the database and queries to exclude this column and all worked fine.

Thanks to @Miguel-F for a quick response.