# displaying image to html from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, base64

Im a newbie. The data already display in the table even the image. but the problem is when i use div id and call this id for using the display of my image from json file. it didnt show the image in div. Any help? Thanks.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Show JSON Data in Jquery Datatables</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css"/>  
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>  


      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <h1 align="center">Show JSON Data in Jquery Datatables</h3><br />  
                <h3 align="center">Employee Database</h3><br />  
                <table id="data-table" class="table table-bordered">  
                     <thead>  
                          <tr>  
                               <th>Name</th>  
                               <th>Gender</th>  
                               <th>Designation</th>
                               <th>Image Path</th>  
                               <th>Support</th>
                          </tr>
                     </thead>  
                </table>  
           </div> 
           <label for="name" id="name">Name</label> 
      <div class="banner-section" id="img-container">
    </div>
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var table= $('#data-table').DataTable({  

           "ajax"     :     "employee_data.json",  
           "columns"     :     [  
                {     "data"     :     "name"     },  
                {     "data"     :     "gender"}  
           ]  

      });
       $('#data-table tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();

    } );



 });  
 </script>
```

JSON FILE

```
{"data":[{"name":"dfghj","gender":"asdfg","designation":"dfgh","image":"<img src=\"data:image\/png;base64,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\">"}]}
```

Comment: it seem you create two time the tag img. try to keep clean the json and write inside only the path of image

Comment: okay so i will not put <img src in the json file?

Comment: surely is strange, you can try to cut off and re-run your code. don't know if is the solution

Comment: maybe this will help you with base64 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64

Comment: but it already displaying in the table . i just want also to display the image in my div class but the problem is the image is not displaying

Comment: if you inspect the code, what is the path of the faulty src?

Comment: it says "GET http://localhost........"(Request-URI Too Long)

Comment: its okay now :D

Comment: i made a little mistake but i fix it already.. Thank you NicolaPez :D