# How can I efficiently store binary data in .js source files?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, compression, binaryfiles

I have a static HTML site, which cannot load any other resources, because it is supposed to work offline as well. The JavaScript code, which is embedded in `<script>` tags, needs to load (and store) a lot of binary data.

Storing the data as an array of numbers is inefficient, a binary-to-text encoding scheme seems to be required. Which one has the highest compression ratio and can still be read and contained within  the `<script>`-tags?

Answer (score 0):

If your page can load .js then probably it also can load any other files, however if you really want to store data in js then use [base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) encoding (here "comparison" with [base128](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135233/860099))