# Retrieve JSON object from Okhttp3 response

Tags: android, okhttp

I want to retrieve a JSON object from Okhttp3 response. Service sends an image as a byte array with its status in a JSON object.

Server response as follows:

```
{
    "msg":"success",
    "msg_code":"001",
    "file":"<200 OK OK,URL [file:/E:/storage/bbb.jpg],[Content-Type:\"image/jpeg\"]>"
}
```

I can retrieve image when the service directly send byte array as the response, using `response.body().bytes()`

But I couldn't when the service sends image data inside JSON object.

Comment: in your json, it is receiving an URL you can use URL to show an image.

Comment: @GaneshGudghe Even URL sends the path, service only provides the image as a byte array. I want to get the byte array from "file" property(see above json object)

Comment: read the JSON and convert file to byte array

Comment: Bytearray in JSON object is not a good idea. You need to send image in base64 or other textual format inside JSON object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64

Answer (score 0):

I think you may get  `response.body().bytes() = null` on main thread because of output steam is already close.
Can you try the same way on "Background thread" by calling `call.execute()`

//Sorry i'm not native English speaker

Comment: I'm calling network request using a background thread and I can get the result when service just sending the byte array as the response. But I can't when service sends the response as a json object.

Comment: Could you provide some source code while convert JSON object to byte array.