# Json deserealization of special symbols

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I want to deserialize blob into custom object.

From blob I get `byte[]`, convert into `string` and then, using `JSON.Net` deserialize into `object`.

```
public object FromByteArray(Type type, byte[] value)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value), type);
}
```

But sometimes there are blobs with special symbols in one of properties.

```
"LogoUrl":"�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u00002\u0000\u0000\u00002\b\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000)�x�\u0000\u0000\u0001,PLTE������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������8�\u0000\u0000\u0001�IDATx^�e��0\u0010��i\u000b�����������%ò�!o�����>\t�ӜC��R�8\"R��I>2;5���+����\u0012=�(\u0010�ݱ�EDi\u0012C��׫\u0003����(\u001a�\u001a��_)\"�vTZ)���z`d\n��\u0010�qO�8�`\\&��ao�U��s\u0012�d\f�0�\u0018�\ty��(L�(���͞\u001c�\u0006[X���1*>a85�\u001d��T�u\u0000��n���0�F�����!xTZT\rU��\t���5��jxM�,�$\u001aۨ���\u0016U�%�*����\u0015�\u0000��7T\u0014�Y\u001a��\u000e���a�\u001c��)�oGB���\u0019ξ�(�c4|&�%�V��g\t��\u0004�4]�\f6ض��\"Fp!jYt�$d�?�ȥ9�pIi�Gh�aE[��;0����Q,C�?\u0003~\u000b,��,��?�J���M[��Nm\u0011�Ky\f��h�c�=D�D%\u0002���>��\"\tow!\u0004S���?��\u0006rI\u0003\u0011n��J�T��#����D�@\u0001��+�' �L\u0012F\u0003\u0004\tA�\u0007r�\bw&cm�\u0001�b\u001f��qi\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000IEND�B`�"
```

It cannot be deserialized by default as I understand. I tried to add `JsonSerializerSettings` with option `StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii` but this doesn't help to solve this issue.

Is there any other way to resolve it?

Tried also deserialize string for 2nd time, this helps to get an object, but not seems like it is the correct way.

Comment: look the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64

Comment: We need to see how the JSON was serialized, or at the minimum, the raw contents of the `byte []` array, to help you.

Answer (score 0):

change your Encoding type from UTF8 to Default

```
public object FromByteArray(Type type, byte[] value)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.Default.GetString(value), type);
}
```

Comment: nope, doesn't help... just symbols become presented in another way in exception