# How do I optimize "ndarray to list" conversion for large number of image matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to convert image matrices to list, in order to send them as a request to an inference API.

However, as most of my files are 100+ pages(I do pdf2img for getting images), the `.tolist()` operation takes a lot of time (Implementation below:)

```
page_images = [page.image.tolist() for page in pages]
```

This single line takes forever to run for 100+ page files.

**Is there something that can be done to improve the speed?**

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question as posted, but what are you doing that can't be done as an ndarray?

Comment: @gph I am converting the data to a list in order to send it in an API request (as ndarrays aren't json serializable), and converting it back to ndarray inside the API

Comment: Gotcha. Could you use an alternative protocol like ftp so you can serialize to something other than json?

Comment: @gph Just realized that while replying to your comment :D.  I'm trying it out right now :)

Comment: if you implement the server side yourself, you could just POST binary data (picture encoded as jpeg or png) rather than json

Comment: You can alternatively try to send the images using base64 encoding inside of json like so: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1443158/502144