# ASP.NET Core Web API - Get file along with [FromBody] JSON model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing API endpoint that receives data from a the client. I want to add the ability to receive files on that endpoint along with the data. This is my model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public IList<IFormFile> File { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Hobbies { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadTest([FromBody] TestModel test)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

I'm currently testing my API with Postman. I know that in Postman there is an option to send files with `form-data` as the body, but in such case my client would need to use `form-data` and I with to use json as data (using `FromBody`).

I can't find a way how to do that - is it possible? And if so, how do I use Postman to send the file view `raw` json?

Comment: You can't combine both a json response AND a file response (that's 2 responses for 1 request).  You will need to have 2 endpoints, one for the json, one for the file(s).

Comment: Could be wrong but, if you're set on doing it in one call, I think the best way would be to encode your binary file client side (for example, with base64) and then unencode when you deserialize. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64

Comment: @Neil Thanks. What would be the best practice in such case to ensure a full transaction? meaning that the client is sure that the server had uploaded the data and the files. Lets say data is uploaded, and now I call to upload files, but file upload fails - the data should be deleted as it's not relevant without the files. Only via form-data?

Comment: There's no automatic way of keeping track of that.  You'll have to come up a scheme that works for you.  @Jonathan 's idea might be better, but it depends on how big your files are.  I worked on a system that required up to 60GB uploads, and that's not practical with his suggestion.

Comment: How do you save the data at the moment, do you use an ORM? And does that db interaction happen directly in the endpoint or do you have that logic somewhere else?

Comment: @Neil It looks like the question is asking how to upload multiple files + data to the web server. Not how to download multiple files + data. Your comments seem to be misunderstanding (though perhaps it's me that's misunderstanding). Maybe developer82 can shed some more light on this.

Comment: @mason You are correct about understanding the question.

Answer (score 12):

When uploading files, if you choose to use JSON, then you are putting the client in a pickle. You are going to force the client to have to Base64-encode all files. This can be a cumbersome task for clients to do especially if it's browser JS code. Not to mention you increase your payload 33%.

### Form-Data?

When posting files, you want to use HTML forms. This is something a browser is *very* good at.

With that being said, the proper way to do this would be to set up your endpoint to look like this:

```
// NOTE: This is the same as you have it in your question
public class TestModel
{
    public IList<IFormFile> File { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Hobbies { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost, Route("testme")]
public IActionResult TestMe([FromForm] TestModel testModel)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Take note of the `[FromForm]` parameter.

Then set up postman to look like this:

[image: Postman]

1. Set it to `Post`.
2. Go to the `Body` section and set it to `Form-Data`.
3. Add in the parameters. You can test multiple files by adding the same parameter name multiple times.
4. Click `Send`.

When the endpoint gets hit, it should look like this:

[image: Post data]

### JSON?

Let's say you absolutely must use JSON as the post data. Then your model will look like this:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public IList<byte[]> File { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Hobbies { get; set; }
}
```

You would change your endpoint from `[FromForm]` to `[FromBody]`, then you will have to convince your front-end devs they must encode all files with `Base64` and build a JSON object to send. I don't think you will be super successful with that as it's not optimized nor is it the norm. They may give you strange looks.

Let's run through the scenario:

1. User selects 3 files. Each are 100 MB a piece.
2. User clicks "submit" and JS now reads 300 MB in to memory.
3. JS encodes 300 MB of files to Base64 in the browser. Memory usage has increased to 400 MB.
4. JS client builds the JSON payload -- Memory increases again as a new string needs to be created based on the 400 MB of strings.
5. Network traffic starts.
6. Backend gets the post data. Since it's JSON, ASP.NET Core will deserialize to your model. The framework will have to allocate 400 MB of memory to read in the JSON from the network.
7. ASP.NET will deserialize, which also requires the decoding of 400 MB of data, which isn't a light task.
8. Your endpoint gets invoked with a ~300MB model *in memory*.

You will run in to OutOfMemory exceptions at some point. It's almost guaranteed.

Form data is extremely optimized in ASP.NET Core. It will use memory for smaller files, but then dump to disk for larger files. It's impossible to run in to memory issues when using Form data.

Let's run though a Form scenario:

1. User selects 3 files. Each are 100 MB a piece.
2. User clicks "submit". Browser will now start a request to the back-end and reads in the file to small chunks of memory and send it up chunk-by-chunk. One file at a time. The size of these chunks are optimized based on environment. Will not exceed what is necessary to transfer the data efficiently. Memory usage will be minimal.
3. ASP.NET starts reading the data. If the `IFormFile` data exceed 5 MB (I believe that's the limit), it will move it from an in-memory stream to a disk stream.
4. ASP.NET invokes your endpoint with references to streams that originate from the disk. The size of your model in memory is irrelevant since it's just holding references to disk streams.

PostMan? There isn't a way to do this in PostMan without scripting something, again because it's not normal to do. I'm sure if you google the subject you may find something, but it will be kludgy at best.

Comment: Thanks for point out my mistake. you don't need to create 2 File Key. Each file can take in multiple data.

Comment: @DamilolaAdegunwa -- Must be a newer feature :) Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("upload")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UploadTest([FromForm] TestModel test)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
    public class TestModel
    {
        public IList<IFormFile> File { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Hobbies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is what the request should look like from postman.

[image]

Here is proof the we got the file.
[image]

Comment: Can you please share what the client call code in c# would look like?   This is just what I'm needing.  Thank you for this post.