# Get file along with [FromBody] JSON model Client Call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Please see this post below,  can you please share what the client call code would look like in c#?  The postman was shared but not the client call code,   I am trying to pass this class below to my webapi

[ASP.NET Core Web API - Get file along with [FromBody] JSON model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724947/asp-net-core-web-api-get-file-along-with-frombody-json-model)

```
public class DtoUploadSPDocument
{
    public string SpDocLibId { get; set; }
    public StreamContent File { get; set; }
    public string UniqueFileName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUploadResultId { get; set; }
    public bool ReturnIsSuccess { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow does not exist to write your code for you.

Comment: You probably won't want to use FromBody.  Just send the form.  Ex: <form><input type='file' name='filetoupload'>...other fields...</form> If you are using JS to send the request, send a FormData() object.  That will send the request as a standard form would.  You'd get the data using [FromForm] in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you changing the property `File` type to `byte[]`. Due to `StreamContent` class, which is part of `System.Net.Http`, is not directly serializable or deserializable using the default JSON serialization.

Then here is a simple demo about how to make a client call to api by using httpclient:

Model

```
public class DtoUploadSPDocument
 {
     public string SpDocLibId { get; set; }
     public byte[] File { get; set; }
     public string UniqueFileName { get; set; }
     public string ReturnUploadResultId { get; set; }
     public bool ReturnIsSuccess { get; set; }

 }
```

Client

```
public async Task UploadApi()
{
    // Replace "your-api-endpoint" with the actual endpoint of your Web API
    string apiUrl = "https://localhost:portnumber/your-api-endpoint";

    // Create an instance of DtoUploadSPDocument
    DtoUploadSPDocument document = new DtoUploadSPDocument
    {
        SpDocLibId = "xxx",
        File = await GetByteFromYourFile(), // Implement this method to get StreamContent from your file
        UniqueFileName = "xxx",
        ReturnUploadResultId = "xxx",
        ReturnIsSuccess = true // or false
    };

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Assuming your API endpoint is configured to accept POST requests
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl, document);
        //do yout stuff...    
    }
}

// Implement this method to convert your file to byte[]
public async Task<byte[]> GetByteFromYourFile()
{
    // For Example
    string filePath = "C:\\your_actual_path\\a.png";   
    byte[] fileBytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath);
    return fileBytes;
}
```

Api

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] DtoUploadSPDocument model)
{
    return Ok(model);
}
```