# Binary data in JSON

Tags: json, binary, udp, hex

I am using JSON because its readable and offers flexibility as a transmission protocol for IPC.  Part of the exchange between processes is a requirement to transfer large binary files (MB's).

I am using UDP and JSON as the transport protocol, in this case the binary data is translated into HEX strings with no delimiters so a single 8 bit character is used to represent each 4 bit nibble.

I'm exploring and looking for ways of keeping the JSON protocol but getting a more efficient way to transferring the binary hex data.

The reason for this is that UDP packets are limited in size and converting each nibble to a byte doubles the bit count and slows down the transfer as the data size is doubled.

Can anyone think of a better way of sending the binary data in a JSON packet without loosing anything?

Comment: The obvious choice would be base64, but also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64#:~:text=The%20JSON%20format%20natively%20doesn,data%20is%20to%20use%20Base64.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Parket to submit information, Parket is a single table binary format, this format is used in machine learning in Python, here are some examples. [Link](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/124548/pyarrow.parquet.write_table) [Link](http://blog.openml.org/openml/data/2020/03/23/Finding-a-standard-dataset-format-for-machine-learning.html)

if your reason is UDP packets maybe try sockets: [Link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#network)
again, :)
I hope it helps you, greetings

Comment: Link doesn't work...also JSON is used throughout the system, this is just a small part of an existing protocol.