# Javascript client-data compression

Tags: javascript, compression, processing.js

I am trying to develop a paint brush application thru processingjs.
This API has function **loadPixels()** that will load the RGB values in to the array.
Now i want to store the array in the server db.

The problem is the size of the array, when i convert to a string the size is 5 MB.

Is the best solution is to do compression at javascript level? How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#JavaScript for an LZW compression example.  It works best on longer strings with repeated patterns.

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel-Ziv-Welch) on LZW:

> A dictionary is initialized to contain
>   the single-character strings
>   corresponding to all the possible
>   input characters (and nothing else
>   except the clear and stop codes if
>   they're being used). The algorithm
>   works by scanning through the input
>   string for successively longer
>   substrings until it finds one that is
>   not in the dictionary. When such a
>   string is found, the index for the
>   string less the last character (i.e.,
>   the longest substring that is in the
>   dictionary) is retrieved from the
>   dictionary and sent to output, and the
>   new string (including the last
>   character) is added to the dictionary
>   with the next available code. The last
>   input character is then used as the
>   next starting point to scan for
>   substrings.
>
> In this way, successively longer
>   strings are registered in the
>   dictionary and made available for
>   subsequent encoding as single output
>   values. The algorithm works best on
>   data with repeated patterns, so the
>   initial parts of a message will see
>   little compression. As the message
>   grows, however, the compression ratio
>   tends asymptotically to the
>   maximum.

Comment: In my case this reduced to 33% of the actual size

Comment: This implementation doesn't work in certain instances. I was encoding a large chunk of HTML and it wasn't decoding properly. Kept returning null. Use this implementation instead: https://gist.github.com/revolunet/843889

Answer (score 1):

[JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip) has a couple answers that are relevant.

Also, [Javascript LZW](http://www.marklomas.net/ch-egg/articles/lzwjs.htm) and [Huffman Coding with PHP and JavaScript](http://code.kuederle.com/huffman) are other implementations I found.