# Client side data compress/decompress?

Tags: javascript, gzip, compression

I'm looking for a JavaScript implementation of a string compress/decompress algorithm where data is created at the client side and stored in hidden fields within HTML forms.

I read about [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/), but it compresses the data server side whereas in my case I want to compress it client side, send it to the server, or receive it from server to decompress it again at client side.

I found this [LZF Compression](http://lzf.childnodes.com/) example based on [LZFjs](https://github.com/pkalogiros/LZFjs) but it will generate binary data which needs to be processed and stored in a hidden form field, and it works on files rather than pure data.

Suggestions on a pure data client-side data compression/decompression that is also efficient?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript client-data compression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252465/javascript-client-data-compression)

Comment: http://danml.com/js/compression.js  you';; want to use atob/btoa to go in-between client and server.

Answer (score 3):

There is this open-source Javascript compression library, by Pierre curto :
https://github.com/pierrec/node-lz4

Googling around, I also found this zlib implementation (not tested by me) :
http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html

Comment: Thanks, but I am not working on a node app, I just need the compression code without the related node integration .. may be two function for compress and de-compress

Comment: It no longer needs 'node', and can be integrated directly within the browser.

Answer (score 3):

You may also try [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/). To run it in browser you just have to [download](http://github.com/Stuk/jszip/zipball/master)  and include dist/jszip.js or dist/jszip.min.js.

This is actively supported and supports a wide variety of browsers including everyone's favorite IE6/7/8!

Usage (from their docs):

> ```
> var zip = new JSZip();
>
> zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
>
> var img = zip.folder("images");
> img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true});
>
> var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
> ```