# Three js displaying 3D images using json file of big size

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a requirement of displaying the 3D images. I have a .obj file that is of the size **80 MB** that I converted to json file which is also nearly **75 MB**.Now using three js I could display rotating 3D image but the issue is speed.It takes **nearly 1 minute to load** the 3D image.

Further client is expecting to display **2 such images** on same page I could do that also but it is taking nearly **4-5 minutes to load images**.

Is there any workaround for **increasing the speed ??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object is 80MB in size then it should not be considered suitable for use in a web application. If the model does not seem to have a high level of detail, then perhaps your exporter has some problem with it and you are getting a lot of extra information that you don't need. If the model simply is very complex, then your only real option is to simplify the model dramatically, or find another model that has a lower polygon count.

If the model has come directly from the client, you are unfortunately going to be faced with the unenviable task of convincing them of the limitations.

If you absolutely have to use these models, perhaps you can try to compress the data and decompress it on the client side. A quick google brought up this Stack Overflow question as a starting point:

[Client side data compress/decompress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275512/client-side-data-compress-decompress)

EDIT: Perhaps you could break it down into separate pieces. Since it is an indexed format, you would probably still have to download all of the vertex data first, and then chunks of the index data.

If you wanted to go deeper you could try breaking the index data into chunks and computing which vertices you would need for each chunk. There is no guarantee that the final result would look that great though, so it might not be worth the effort. That said, with some analysis you could probably rearrange the indices so the model loaded in a sensible order, say from front to back, or left to right.

If you have a 3d artist at your disposal, it might be easier to break the model down into several models and load them one by one into the scene. This would probably look much cleaner since you could make artistic choices about where to cut the model up.

Comment: Unfortunately the file is shared by client and it contains high level of details.If I compress the file then still it would be of size 30 MB or 40 MB. Is there any way like parsing the json file in parts ??

Comment: Hi. I added some additional ideas to my answer above.

Comment: Hi @Jaydeep S. I hope you don't mind me asking, but I notice that you just joined Stack Overflow, and possibly you don't realise how it works. If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind ticking it as the "correct" answer? That way I will get some reputation points, and the answer will be marked for other users as being of value. I hope you solved your problem... If you came up with a good solution, perhaps you could report back so others can learn from your experience. Thanks!