# How does this javascript compression technique works?

Tags: javascript, compression, xss, obfuscation

I was checking the results of a security contest involving XSS ([link](https://cure53.de/xmas2013/writeup)) and found some wonderful and scary JS XSS payloas. The winner (@kinugawamasato) used a javascript compression technique that seems completely other worldly to me:

Compressed payload:

```
https://cure53.de/xmas2013/?xss=<scriPt>document.write(unescape(escape(location)
.replace(/u(..)/g,'$1%')))<\/scriPt>㱯扪散琠楤㵥⁣污獳楤㵣汳楤㨳㌳䌷䉃㐭㐶うⴱㅄ〭
䉃〴ⴰ〸ぃ㜰㔵䄸㌠潮牯睥湴敲㵡汥牴⠯繷⸪ℱ⼮數散⡲散潲摳整⠰⤩⤾㱳癧⁯湬潡搽攮摡瑡畲氽慬汛攮
牯睤敬業㴳㍝⬧㽳慮瑡㵀Ⅱ汬潷彤潭慩湳㴧⭤潭慩渻攮捨慲獥琽❵瑦ⴷ✾
```

What really happened:

```
<object id=e classid=clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83 onrowenter=alert(/~w.*!1/.exec(recordset(0)))><svg onload=e.dataurl=all[e.rowdelim=33]+'?santa=@!allow_domains='+domain;e.charset='utf-7'>
```

Is this technique already documented somewhere so I can study it? How exacly this thing works? Is there already some javascript compressor that does that in an automated way? How would a WAF react to such a payload like that?

You can see more examples [here](https://cure53.de/xmas2013/writeup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using [lz-string](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) library for JS compression whenever placing any data into `localStorage`. I am just a user of this library - not the compression expert. But this is information which could be found around that tool...

The [lz-string](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) Goal:

> lz-string was designed to fulfill the need of storing large amounts of data in `localStorage`, specifically on mobile devices. localStorage being usually limited to 5MB, all you can compress is that much more data you can store.
>
> ...
>   I *(note: "I" means, Pieroxy, author of the lz-string)* started out from an LZW implementation (no more patents on that), which is very simple...

So, the fundament, the base of this implemntation is LZW, which is mentioned here [Javascript client-data compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252465/) by [Andy E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2252533/1679310). Let me point out

- the link to [Wikipedia article on LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel-Ziv-Welch)
- the [LZW compression example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#JavaScript).

An extract from [Wikipedia - Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel-Ziv-Welch#Algorithm):

> The scenario described by Welch's 1984 encodes sequences of 8-bit data as fixed-length 12-bit codes. The codes from 0 to 255 represent 1-character sequences consisting of the corresponding 8-bit character, and the codes 256 through 4095 are created in a dictionary for sequences encountered in the data as it is encoded. At each stage in compression, input bytes are gathered into a sequence until the next character would make a sequence for which there is no code yet in the dictionary. The code for the sequence (without that character) is added to the output, and a new code (for the sequence with that character) is added to the dictionary.

[Wikipedia - Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel-Ziv-Welch#Encoding):

> A high level view of the encoding algorithm is shown here:
>
> 1. Initialize the dictionary to contain all strings of length one.
> 2. Find the longest string W in the dictionary that matches the current input.
> 3. Emit the dictionary index for W to output and remove W from the input.
> 4. Add W followed by the next symbol in the input to the dictionary.
> 5. Go to Step 2.

How it works in case of the lz-string we can observer here:

- The source code: [lz-string-1.3.3.js](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/blob/master/libs/lz-string-1.3.3.js)

Let me cite few steps from the already mentioned [lz-string source](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html):

> What I did was:
>
> - localStorage can only contain JavaScript strings. Strings in JavaScript are stored internally in UTF-16, meaning every character weight 16 bits. I modified the implementation to work with a 16bit-wide token space.
> - I had to remove the default dictionary initialization, totally useless on a 16bit-wide token space.
> - I initialize the dictionary with three tokens:
>
>   - An entry that produces a 16-bit token.
>   - An entry that produces an 8-bit token, because most of what I will store is in the iso-latin-1 space, meaning tokens below 256.
>   - An entry that mark the end of the stream.
> - The output is processed by a bit stream that stores effectively 16 bits per character in the output string.
> - Each token is stored with just as many bits that are needed according to the size of the dictionary. Hence, the first token takes 2 bits, the second to 7th three bits, etc....

Well, now we know, that by these compression techniques we get 16 bits information. We can test it in this demo: http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/demo.html *(or/and another [here](http://nmrugg.github.io/LZMA-JS/demos/advanced_demo.html))*

Which converts the: `Hello, world.` into

```
85 04 36 30 f6 60 40 03 0e 04 01 e9 80 39 03 26
00 a2
```

So we need the final step, let me cite again:

> Well, this lib produces stuff that isn't really a string. By using all 16 bits of the UTF-16 bitspace, those strings aren't exactly valid UTF-16. By version 1.3.0, I added two helper encoders to produce stuff that we can do something with:
>
> - `compress` produces invalid UTF-16 strings. Those can be stored in `localStorage` only on webkit browsers (Tested on Android, Chrome, Safari). Can be decompressed with `decompress`

to continue our example, the `Hello, world.` would be converted into

```
҅〶惶̀Ў㦀☃ꈀ
```

And that's finally it. We can see, that the set of all the *...other then latin characters...* comes from the final conversion into UTF-16. Hope, this will give some hints...

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow! :)