# How to decompress using gzip in MVC Using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my code

Client:

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: Employee/Save,
headers: {'Content-Encoding':'gzip'},
data: { fname :  $scope.fName , lname: $scope.lName}
}).success(function () {});
```

Controller

```
public async Task<JsonNetResult> Save(EmployeeModel empData)
{

}
```

In the above code when i pass Content-Encoding header in http post the employee data not assign the EmployeeModel only null values are assigned. But without passing Content-Encoding header data pass to the MVC controller . Now how to decompress data in MVC when use `Content-Encoding:'gzip'` in MVC using c#.net.

UPDATE:

```
public class EmployeeModel { 
    public string fName{ get; set; } 
    public string lName{ get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Show `EmployeeModel`. make sure that the properties match.

Comment: public class EmployeeModel
    {
         public string fName{ get; set; }
         public string lName{ get; set; }
    }

Comment: @durgasivakishoremopuru Are you absolutely sure you need compression? Is this your bottleneck?

Answer (score 1):

According to this similar question [AngularJS compress $http post data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32246863/5233410)

> Angular has no compression utilities.
>
> If you really need to compress then you will have to find a JavaScript
>   library to do so, which I know nothing about, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip) and
>   [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252465/javascript-client-data-compression) would be good places to start.

Comment: That is also Not working, Where write the decompression code for gzip in MVC

Comment: That code i already wrote , That code working fine but that one is compress the code from mvc to angular , now i want decompress code from angular to mvc

Comment: just for trouble shooting. did you get it to work with out gzip?

Comment: yes without gzip working fine but i want to compress data and pass from angular to mvc

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32246863/5233410 you cannot out of the box as angular has no compression utilities